# Get Bitcoin Wallet balance with Python

Tags: wallet, python, balance

On a tutorial in [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=um9omi943jw)
it uses [pybitcointools](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools). Upon searching it's github repository, I have found that it was [not maintained](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/issues/447) anymore. Are there any alternative to this library which can get wallet balance?

Thank you.

Comment: i assume you want to create a wallet for bitcoin, here the lib for that: https://github.com/1200wd/bitcoinlib

Comment: Try this one https://github.com/mcdallas/cryptotools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a Bitcoin node to execute RPC calls against (i.e. you're running `bitcoind` with the RPC turned on), you can do this rather simply with pyjsonrpc:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pyjsonrpc import ServiceProxy

bitcoin = ServiceProxy("http://127.0.0.1:8332")  # this is your bitcoind node and RPC port
bitcoin.username = 'testuser'  # rpcuser
bitcoin.password = 'testpass'  # rpcpassword
print(bitcoin.getbalance())
```

Comment: Thank you @Motoma. I am not aware if I have run any local RPC node unless pybitcointools is running it on the background. My intent is to have a personalized payment gateway and be able to track balances of multiple wallet addresses.

Comment: @CodeJammer In that case, you'll need to run a local Bitcoin node in addition to the script above. Doing that is probably beyond the scope of this question, but Bitcoin Core or Bcoin are two such options for running a local node.